# Can I access Gmail's spam message folder using pop3/imap?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, spam-prevention, pop3

If I use pop3/imap to read my gmail via a desktop client can I also set it to show emails that google automatically puts into the spam folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With IMAP, yes. The Spam folder is available as `[Gmail]/Spam`.

POP3 is very limited, and only allows accessing messages from `INBOX`. This is limitation of POP3 itself.

Comment: This worked for me for many years, but it seems to have stopped working (recently?).

Comment: I can confirm I do not see the spam folder in imapfilter's mailbox or folder listings.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to access spam messages using pop3, you can create a filter to never place e-mail in the spam folder. According to http://aaron-kelley.net/blog/2008/08/disable-gmail-spam-filter-include-spam-in-pop3-download/

1. Go to gmail.com
2. Create a new filter
3. Type * in the From field
4. In the next screen, select "Never send it to spam"
5. POP3 now downloads spam too